# H12 error on Heroku when running my node.js program

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm getting a H12 error when I try to run my app on Heroku. Here's the error.

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=zevsbot.herokuapp.com request_id=fa37cd30-9f13-4bd2-bc6a-de4b9c0709a2 fwd="202.21.107.88" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

My Procfile

```
web: node index.js
```

Here's my index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.render;
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'))
});
```

Here's my package.json file if it helps or something

```
{
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "bundle": "^2.1.0",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.9.8",
    "steam-tradeoffer-manager": "^2.9.5",
    "steam-user": "^4.8.0",
    "steamcommunity": "^3.40.0",
    "tf2": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "name": "bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Zev",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "Wow",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.3"
  }
}
```

If you guys could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function(){ console.log('Your node js server is running'); });

Comment: This seems to have fixed my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function(){ console.log('Your node js server is running'); });